# How to add a scroll to the buttons container?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have this buttons which have a hover effect that renders a span on top of the hovered button.

[image]

It works fine, but, when the width of the screen changes, it looks very bad:

[image]

These are the elements:

```
<div className='buttons'>
                <button
                    className={editor.isActive('bold') ? 'is-active' : 'is-inactive'}
                >
                    <strong>N</strong>
                    <span className='popup'>Negrita (Ctrl+B)</span>
                </button>
                <button
                    className={editor.isActive('italic') ? 'is-active' : 'is-inactive'}
                >
                    <em>C</em>
                    <span className='popup'>Cursiva (Ctrl+I)</span>
                </button>
                <button
                    className={editor.isActive('strike') ? 'is-active' : 'is-inactive'}
                >
                    <s>T</s>
                    <span className='popup'>Tachado (Ctrl+Shift+X)</span>
                </button>
                ... (you get the idea) 
</div>
```

This is the scss:

```
.buttons button {
    position: relative;
    height: 29.19px;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    margin: 0.2rem !important;
    padding: 0.1rem 0.4rem !important;
    background: white;
    accent-color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
}

button .popup {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

button .popup::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

button:hover .popup {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

## What im looking for

I decided that the best solution would be a horizontal scroll. The problem is that the span is absolute positioned based on the button so i cant figure it out a way to keep the span on top of the hovered button while having an **horizontal** scroll.

## Update 1

Ok, i tried to add a scroll, this is whats happening now:

[image]

As you can see, the scroll is working fine but the spans are 'covered', is there a way to fix this?

I added this to the code:

```
.buttons {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to give it the `buttons` class a fixed width and `overflow-x: scroll`?

Comment: Yes, i tried, this is what happens: https://imgur.com/a/eY5aTO2

Comment: Hello @IgnacioPasserini, try replicating your problem with actual code so that we can help you out. I can think of a couple solutions that might work - one of them is use `position:fixed` for the tooltip and apply negative margins to position it and the other would be to remove `position:relative` from your overflown container and place it on a parent element instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the definition of the `absolute` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative
> to its closest **positioned ancestor**, if any; otherwise, it is placed
> relative to the initial containing block.

And **positioned ancestor**:

> A positioned element is an element whose computed position value is
> either relative, absolute, fixed, or sticky. (In other words, it's
> anything except static.)

So, it should work even while having an horizontal scroll if you set `position:relative` for `.buttons`.